# how to build an extjs form from object defined in domain class

Tags: grails, extjs

I have seen a grails domain class having something like this defined:

```
static formLayout =
    [   title:"New Patient Patient",
        layout: "custom",
        autoHeight:true,
        items:
        [
            [
                layout: 'column',
                labelWidth: 135,
                items:
                [[
                    columnWidth: 0.5,
                    layout: 'form',
                    items:["patientNo", "dob","surName"]
                ],[
                    columnWidth: 0.5,
                    layout: 'form',
                    items:["responsibleDoctor","givenName","sex.value"]
                ]]
            ],
...
]
```

All I want to know is how can this be used/called either from an extjs file or controller file so it appears as a form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a common approach to have javaScript parameters defined in Domain classes for the consumption of the views.

However, Assuming that you are looking at a code base that applied such approach, if I am not mistaken the view that is consuming them is sending an ajax call to a controller and reads these values as **JSON**. I am not much familiar with extJs, but it should be able to consume parameters as JSON. For example, `Ext.create` has option url that hits the external source. If you are looking at a code base that is using this approach you should be able find the view and controller that is delivering and consuming it.